# Finite dimensional subalgebra of continuous functions

Tags: real-analysis

Let $V \subset C(\mathbb{R})$ be a finite dimensional vector space that is closed under multiplication, how to show that $V$ consists only of constant functions? Any hints will be much appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

Let $f$ be any function in $V$. Then $\{f,f^{2},f^{3}, ...\}$ are linearly dependent. Hence there is a polynomial $p$ such that $p(f(x))=0$ for all $x$. This means the range of $f$ lies in the roots of $p$. So the range is finite. But $f$ is continuous so IVP shows that $f$ must be a constant.